# Unique Permission is not working in SharePoint Online Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement on SharePoint Online Document Library. I have to give some unique permission (Users/Groups) to the SharePoint Document Library. But anyhow it is not working for me.

When I will give permission to the SharePoint Online Document Library, then those specific users only can see the particular Document library.

But here, in my case, As I have permission to that library So that I only can see the library. But when I am logging in with another user account, there also I can see that library which should not be. Because the other user doesn't have any permission to that library.

Can anyone suggest how can I handle this issue?
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

**First**, validate that you do indeed have "Unique" permissions on your document library:
If you go to "Library Settings" for your document library, then click on "Permissions for this document library", this takes you to the Advanced permission management for the library.  Once on this permission management page, at the top-left of the page in the "ribbon", if you see the buttons "Manage Parent" and "Stop Inheriting Permissions" (see screenshot), then this library is still accessible to users who have site level permission.

[image: Screenshot of Inherited Permissions Ribbon Buttons]

If this is the case, then you need to click on the "Stop Inheriting Permissions" button to ensure that your library has unique permissions.

**Second**, once you have ensured that the library has unique permissions, the buttons should now look like the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Unique Permissions Ribbon Buttons]

In that case, click the right-most button in that ribbon to "Check Permissions".  In here you can type the username of a user to check.  If you check the name of the user who can see the library, this permission check will tell you through which group that user has access.

**Final Note**:  If you have already gone a step deeper and are using unique permissions on individual documents within this library to give access to users who would not have access to the Library, those users will now be able to "see" the library, although the only items they will be able to see inside the library are the ones with explicitly granted access.